# Copy File only if Source File Exists

Tags: cmake

I'm wanting to add a custom command to my CMake which copies files from a project (build separate from the rest of the CMake projects) into a directory usable by the CMake projects that need it. This is simple enough:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS -E copy_if_different ${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE} "${LIGHT_THEME_REF}"
)
```

The problem is, that the `${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}` doesn't always exist, so this causes an error. Is it possible to change the command to only copy if the **source** file exists? The destination file will always exist, so it's not the problem. (to clarify, the variable `${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}` will exist, just not necessarily the file it refers to)

I'd like to try to do it as part of the custom command, if possible, since when CMake generates the project files the source file might not exist, but then later on the source file would. If that's not possible, and it has to be done when CMake is generating, that's acceptable though.

For reference, currently using CMake 3.22, but can use later versions if needed.

Comment: side-question: why not just use a symlink? CMake supports making cross-platform symlinks ([`cmake -E create_symlink`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-create_symlink) and [`file(CREATE_LINK)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#create-link))

Comment: The original, `${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}` in this case, might not actually exist on the machine at all, so wouldn't be able to create a symlink.

Comment: Maybe you can add a check to determine if the file exists or not?

```
if (EXISTS ${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE})
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    ARGS -E copy_if_different ${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE} "${LIGHT_THEME_REF}"
)
endif(EXISTS ${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE})
```

Comment: @Life4gal that check will only happen at configuration time and not during the execution of the custom command.

Comment: @Life4gal, that would be a fall back if I couldn't get it to work as part of the custom command. user's solution seems to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do the check at configuration time, then use [`if(EXISTS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#exists).

If you need the check with the execution of the custom command, write a script that does the check and only copies the file if the check passes, and then call that script in your custom command.

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        "-DLIGHT_THEME_SOURCE=${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}"
        "-DLIGHT_THEME_REF=${LIGHT_THEME_REF}"
        -P cmake/copy_theme.cmake
)
```

cmake/copy_theme.cmake:

```
if(EXISTS "${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}")
    file(COPY_FILE "${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}" "${LIGHT_THEME_REF}" ONLY_IF_DIFFERENT)
endif()
```

Comment: Been meaning to comment for the last 2 weeks, but kept forgetting. I did also have to change the parameters. Using `-D` like you mentioned, and like I usually would when calling cmake, actually doesn't set the variables. The parameters just get passed in as the cmake args 3 and 4; so I changed the copy_theme.cmake to use those instead.

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm confused by what you mean. Could you elaborate on what you changed, or suggest it as an edit?

Comment: When passing `-DLIGHT_THEME_SOURCE=${LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE}` to copy_theme.cmake, I didn't end up with a variable called `LIGHT_THEME_SOURCE`, I instead ended up with a variable called `CMAKE_ARGV3` which had the value of `-DLIGHT_THEME_SOURCE=C:/Projects/.../light.dll` ... Though, I think it's because the `-D` parameters should be _before_ the `-P cmake/copy_theme.cmake`. Can't test right now, wrong computer.

Comment: @ChrisMM yep. I just checked the docs and I put the order of arguments wrong. I just edited to fix it. sorry about that.